# Alfresco Query not working

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I tried to search documnet with its property and document name
i used following query.
I used cmis API to search records

```
select * from my:content where my:customnode Like '%Test' or cmis:name
 Like '%Test%'
```

Its not working..I didn't search my record by document name..
I search record from my custom model.
If i search record by only property like my:customnode,my:address then it gives output successfully.
But When I used cmis:name then it didn't work.

How can I search document by its name??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake is not adding a where clause for each aspect you are searching on.
If the property my:customnode (I'm guessing this is a property otherwise this is the problem) is part of an aspect you need to do a join like this:

...    from my:content JOIN my:aspect as ma where ma.my:customprop like ...

Comment: But I have only one  custom model my:content.I want to search By title and properties..If I search like.. Selct * from my:content where cmis:name like 'test%' then I got successful output..But when I use this query Select * from my:content where cmis:name like 'test%' or my:customprop like 'test%' then I got nothing in result...

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work the problem is not the cmis:name column.
I just tried the following query on my repository and it worked as expected:

```
select * from my:DocumentDetails 
where my:DocumentTitle like '%Test%' 
   or cmis:name like '%23%'
```

Comment: I tried the same..but didn't work..Do I have to change any custom model files??

Comment: I didn't give me result title like %test% but I have in alfresco

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, this seems a problem with lucene or solr indexes.

Have you tested your query in the "Node Browser"? You can execute the same search with CMIS and with a lucene query. If it does not work with the lucene query, check your indexes.